# How can I create tables Dynamically in a VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, tag

Hi My situation is this:

I have a list of different objects and every object has different fields, How can I create N Different Tables in a [visualforce](/questions/tagged/visualforce) page ??

Example.
I have this list in an [apex](/questions/tagged/apex) class controller

```
ObjectName----FieldName <br>
Account---------Name<br>
Account---------LastName<br>
Account---------address<br>
Case------------Name<br>
Case------------Status<br>
```

So, with this info I have to display two different tables in a [visualforce](/questions/tagged/visualforce) page like this:

```
Account table<br>
Name----LastName----Address

Case Table<br>
Name----Status
```

In my project I may have even 10 different objects so, I would need 10 different tables created by themself in the [visualforce](/questions/tagged/visualforce), with different number of columns.

I have no Idea how to do this.. someone can help me and save my life???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use [Dynamic Visualforce Components](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_dynamic_vf_components_intro.htm) to build up various [apex:pageBlockTable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm) in Apex. With this you can programmatically build up the required apex:column's and bindings.

Your Visualforce page will be something like:

```
<apex:page controller="DynamicController">
    <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!dynamicPanel}"/>
</apex:page>
```

With a backing Controller class:

```
public with sharing Class DynamicController {
    public Component.Apex.OutputPanel getDynamicPanel() {
        Component.Apex.OutputPanel outPanel = new Component.Apex.OutputPanel();

        // Here you will build up the required dynamic components and add them to panel.

        return outPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was researshing about it and apparently this is the way, but, Im quite new in salesforce, and I dont know how to build now the tables...no idea how to do this... I mean, I need to know how having the columns and headers, how to build it! I dont know how!

Comment: @user4882 With [Dynamic Visualforce Components](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-vf-component) I find it easiest to build a static version first in a Visualforce page, and then convert it into the required apex. Have a look at some of the [other questions](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-vf-component) and the Salesforce documents for more tips.